# trying to split video in segments using ffmpeg but audio/video has a few more frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to split a video in multiple segments.

The ffmpeg is called with this options :

`./ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel debug -ss 5  -i <sourceUrl> -f mpegts -profile:v high -t 5 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -preset medium segment_01.ts`

so from this i create a list of ts segments and use them to create a m3u8 playlist.

The issue is between the segments, the audio is half of second longer than the video.

Is there any option to cut the audio precisely? Is maybe the problem from something else ?

P.S.  I do not want to use the HLS option.

Comment: So you increment the `-ss` and `-t` parameters in order to create each segment? I wouldn't do that and instead use the `segment` muxer, or the `hls` muxer. Please explain why you don't want to use the HLS muxer.

Comment: because i am using aws lambda for segments creation, converting a video in under a minute. With the -ss before input i load only the part of the video i need from an s3 bucket.

Comment: I remember having had similar problems with manual segmenting where the duration for audio and video tracks is slightly different. Using the segment muxer (or hls muxer) works fine since it takes care of the start time / offset of the individual segments.

Comment: yes, it works fine with the muxer but that is not what i need unfortunately

Comment: I think you're solving the wrong kind of problem then. I know it's a limitation of AWS that they don't offer small segment encoding, and that their Elastic encoder service is charged by the minute. You may be able to fiddle around with the timestamps of the generated segments, but I don't know off the top of my head what would be the best solution.

Comment: that is what i did, used the timestamps. It fixed some of the problem, almost to perfection but there is still a difference between segments.